# alexa how to use elicit slot from python lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a `custom alexa skill` where I have an `intent`, named `intentone`, and this intent has 2 `slots` - `slotone` and `slottwo`. When this intent is invoked it calls the `python` `lambda function`. Now from this `python` `lambda function` I want to `elicitSlot` value for `slotone` and after user provides response then `elcitSlot` for `slottwo`.

I wrote this code which just sends a static response to user after the intent is invoked and I am not able to add `elicitSlot` into this:

```
##############################
# Builders
##############################
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def build_PlainSpeech(body):
    speech = {}
    speech['type'] = 'PlainText'
    speech['text'] = body
    return speech


def build_response(message, session_attributes={}):
    response = {}
    response['version'] = '1.0'
    response['sessionAttributes'] = session_attributes
    response['response'] = message
    return response


##############################
# Responses
##############################


def conversation(title, body, session_attributes):
    speechlet = {}
    speechlet['outputSpeech'] = build_PlainSpeech(body)
    speechlet['shouldEndSession'] = False
    return build_response(speechlet, session_attributes=session_attributes)


def statement(title, body):
    speechlet = {}
    speechlet['outputSpeech'] = build_PlainSpeech(body)
    speechlet['shouldEndSession'] = True
    return build_response(speechlet)


##############################
# Custom Intents
##############################


def intentone(event, context):
    session_attributes = {}
    respnse = "Would you like to order a large or regular"

    return conversation("order_size", respnse,session_attributes)



##############################
# Required Intents
##############################


def cancel_intent():
    return statement("CancelIntent", "You want to cancel")  #don't use CancelIntent as title it causes code reference error during certification 


def help_intent():
    return statement("CancelIntent", "You want help")       #same here don't use CancelIntent


def stop_intent():
    return statement("StopIntent", "You want to stop")      #here also don't use StopIntent


##############################
# On Launch
##############################


def on_launch(event, context):
    return statement("title", "body")


##############################
# Routing
##############################


def intent_router(event, context):

    logger.debug("EVENT REQUEST RECEIVED = {}".format(event))
    intent = event['request']['intent']['name']

    # Custom Intents

    if intent == "intentone":
        return intentone(event, context)

    # Required Intents

    if intent == "AMAZON.CancelIntent":
        return cancel_intent()

    if intent == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return help_intent()

    if intent == "AMAZON.StopIntent":
        return stop_intent()


##############################
# Program Entry
##############################


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event, context)

    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return intent_router(event, context)
```

I looked around for `elicitSlot` examples in python but couldn't find one. Majority of examples show `Node.js` example of `this.emit()` as in this [link](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/95956/example-of-elicitslot.html). 
How can I implement `elicitSlot` in python lambda function. A simple example would be helpful to get an idea about it

Answer (score -2):

Hi you will have to use the dialog feature. Unfortunately I dont have any examples right now. Please google it

Comment: Thanks for trying to help the OP!  Would you please do the Googling and [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49459260/edit) with what you find?  Otherwise, I would recommend deleting your answer, since it will attract downvotes.  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more about how things run around here.  Much appreciated!